# Arduino Uno wifi Mqtt Connector setup

Tags: arduino, wifi, mqtt, arduino-uno-wifi

I'm using the Arduino UNO Wifi Developer edition and trying to get MQTT running on it. As per the documentation here http://www.arduino.org/learning/reference/ciao-mqtt it requires setting up the connector by change the mqtt conf file. The question is how do i do that? What are the steps to update this file and where does this file even reside?

It shows the path of the file but i'm not sure how to reach that file, does this file reside on the Arduino board or is it on the Arduino IDE file system?

If it is on the Arduino board how do it edit the file there, using what software?

Comment: The link you provide explains how to change the file. Edit the question to explain what exactly you are having problems with

Answer (score 0):

The ciao-mqtt client is for use with the newer arduino boards that have a on board arm processor that runs a flavour of Linux. Boards like the Yun

The file it mentions is hosted in the Linux side of the board.

If you want to do MQTT on a "normal" arduino board look at this client

http://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/

Comment: Hi hardlib, thanks for your suggestions, but since i'm using the Adruino Uno Wifi, what would be Ethernet client? The WifiClient does not work?